# SQL SERVER CODE for TEXT Search from one Table with the customer ID and the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below code but it is running very slow. Could you please
let me know about any suggestions you may have?

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [W].[CUST] 
,[M].[Add_Text]
    FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[CUST] AS W
    JOIN [XXXX].[dbo].[TRANS] As M
        ON [M].[Add_Text] LIKE '%' + [W].[CUST] + '%'
```

So, it is looking for any CUST entries under CUST table and matching it with Add_Text since the IDs are embedded as a part of the Add_Text and there not another way to join these tables.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is this part `LIKE '%' + [W].[CUST] + '%'`

This is not [SARGable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) which means an index can not be used. See [this blog on why this is slow.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/)

You can speed this up by removing the leading `%` if you don't care about preceding fuzzy matches.

Other than that, we'd need to see the execution plan. But here are some random potentials:

- Outdated Statistics
- Under sized server (memory / cpu)
- Internal Fragmentation